# Angular js tab application

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to make an angularjs application, with tabs and dynamic content (relative to the tabs). I would like to load the content from a json file like this:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Hejsa",
    "text": "Hej jeg hedder Jonas"
  },
  {
    "title": "Halløjsa",
    "text": "Du er dum"
  },
  {
    "title": "Tab 3",
    "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
  }
]
```

I would like to format the data like this:

```
<div class="panels">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <blockquote>
    Text
  </blockquote>
</div>
```

And then i would like to call it as a custom directive, like this:

```
<tabs-body tabs="number of tabs"></tabs-body>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You've listed the planned requirements for your project, but you haven't stated what part of this project you're having a problem with. You can't just list requirements, say thanks, and expect someone to write the entire rest of your application for you. You need to ask a clear question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go with https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ and in detail https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/tabs or https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tabs.

The other solution would be to write your own logic but I would expect SO to help you with a particular problem not with providing you with a code...